# Why in my code private data members are inaccessible?

Tags: c++

Why am I not able to access `a` and `b`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class x;
class y
{
    int a;

public:
    void setdata(int val)
    {
        a = val;
    }
    friend void add(x, y);
};
class x
{
    int b;

public:
    void setdata(int val)
    {
        b = val;
    }
    friend void add(x, y);
};
void add(y o1, x o2)
{
    cout << "the sum is: " << o1.a + o2.b;
}
int main()
{
    x obj1;
    obj1.setdata(4);

    y obj2;
    obj2.setdata(9);
    add(obj1, obj2);
}
```

https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/2R99AKXvTg

Comment: `void add(y, x)` vs. `void add(x, y)`.

Comment: thanks for that! can u tell why that happened?

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that your definition(the order of parameters) of `add` does not match with the friend declaration you have for `add` inside the class.

To **solve**, just modify your `add` definition to:

```
void add(x o1, y o2)
{
    cout << "the sum is: " << o1.b + o2.a;
}
```

This definition of `add` matches the friend declaration you had inside the classes.

The program then works as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/7GWshXAQH).